# npm install --prefix Создаются файлы .cmd, .ps1

Tags: node.js, windows, cmd, npm, powershell

У меня Windows 10, использую powershell.
Есть папка backend, в которой лежит package.json для backend
В моём [проекте](https://github.com/mihinov/crm-angular/commit/dba0ddd59360fa46e350b5d5a7f3bde96a05a5e9) из корневой папки пытаюсь сделать
`npm install --prefix backend`
В итоге получаю такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и всё успешно загружено, все команды из папки backend работают, но появляются эти файлы.
Та же самая история и с папкой client.
Я могу вручную зайти в папку и написать npm install и всё нормально будет. Но я хочу настроить package.json, чтобы из папки проекта можно было установить сразу и backend и client

Comment: А зачем вы используете prefix?

Comment: @AlexeyTen чтобы команда npm install сработала из контекста другой папки. Я пробовал запускать на UNIX, там не было проблем